# Como agrego una fila por cada 10 filas que se llamen desde una tabla usando foreach y for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

Estoy llamando los registros de una tabla con un `foreach`, además quiero crear una fila divisora (por llamarla así) entre cada diez registros generados, me llega la idea de hacerlo con `for`. Esta respuesta me ayudaría mucho.

Comment: tenes que agregar tu codigo, para que queres agregar una fila vacia? seria para hacer un separador visual?

Comment: Imagina que tengo un `foreach(var ítem in módel){}` se mostrarán todos los registros que tengo en esa tabla y entre cada diez ítems se creará una nueva fila, no estará vacía, pondré ahí una información pertinente.

Comment: podes usar metodo insert sobre tu coleccion, ejem model.Insert(indice, turegistro); tenes que usar matematica para saber, o hacer un for(int i=0; i<cantidad; i+=10)

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Ten en cuenta que tu pregunta puede atraer más atención y generar interés en responderla si incluyeras el código que has intentado y nos comentes donde estás teniendo dificultades. Otra lectura que recomiendo es [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes añadir un contador = 0 y sumar en cada vuelta del bucle.
Luego dentro del bucle pones:

```
@if(contador % 10 == 0){
   <div>Linea con datos</div>
}
```

Si usas for, seria parecido, pero el contador ya lo tienes en el propio if, entonces seria algo asi:

```
@if(i % 10 == 0){
   <div>Linea con datos</div>
}
```